# JQuery switching cursor icons

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site with a video on the front page.

This video plays automatically.  I want the user to be able to stop it by clicking.  This has been answered elsewhere and this works.

HOWEVER I want to swap the cursor icon depending on whether the next click will play or pause the video.

Currently I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#videointro").hover(function(event) {
        if(event.type === "mouseenter") {
            jQuery(this).attr("controls", "");
        } else if(event.type === "mouseleave") {
            jQuery(this).removeAttr("controls");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

and css of:

```
#videointro:hover {
    cursor:url(images/ButtonPause-01.png), auto;
}
```

...and basically no clue as to where I can go with this.

Hoping someone can shine a light on this please.

Cheers
Dave

Comment: There isn't a css class to indicate whether the video is paused or playing is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest method is to assign custom class names for play and pause and assign different cursors based on class name. If the video player is in playing state then set the class as `playing` otherwise set the class as `paused`.

Give custom cursors with

```
.playing{
  cursor:url(images/ButtonPause-01.png), auto;
 }

.paused{
  cursor:url(images/ButtonPlay-01.png), auto;
}
```

You can detect the paused status with `paused` property of video player which will be a boolen value. This can be checked in the hover and click events

```
if((jQuery(this)[0].paused))
     jQuery(this).addClass("paused").removeClass("playing");
    else
     jQuery(this).addClass("playing").removeClass("paused");
```

Which will add `paused` class if video is not playing otherwise add `playing` class.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#videointro").click(function(){
    (jQuery(this)[0].paused)?jQuery(this)[0].play():jQuery(this)[0].pause();
    if((jQuery(this)[0].paused))
     jQuery(this).addClass("paused").removeClass("playing");
    else
     jQuery(this).addClass("playing").removeClass("paused");
 });
 
 jQuery("#videointro").hover(function(event) {
 if((jQuery(this)[0].paused))
     jQuery(this).addClass("paused").removeClass("playing");
    else
     jQuery(this).addClass("playing").removeClass("paused");
        
    if(event.type === "mouseenter")
       jQuery(this).attr("controls", "");
    else if(event.type === "mouseleave")
       jQuery(this).removeAttr("controls");
    });
});
```

```css
.paused{
   cursor:url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/games/gam-13/gam1232.png), auto;
}

.playing{
  cursor:url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/cur-1/cur1.png),auto;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
<video class="playing" autoplay="true" id="videointro" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you Tintu that has solved the cursor change issue.  
Many thanks.

However the video does not now pause when clicked.

Cheers
Dave